# Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode. \section{INTRODUÇÃO}

Tags: titlesec

How can I solve this issue?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{txfonts}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \setlength\parindent{1.25cm}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \singlespacing
    \usepackage[bottom=2cm,top=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

    %\usepackage{titling}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\textbf}

    \begin{document}
    \section{INTRODUÇÃO} % THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use a font *declaration* rather than a *macro*. That is, `\bfseries` rather than `\textbf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\section{INTRODUÇÃO}
\end{document}
```